# Colon or dash as a separator in a headline

Tags: punctuation

I’m creating a headline (for my online [digest](http://webplatformdaily.org/)), and I’m wondering if I should use a dash

> Web Animations API - grouping and sequencing animations

or a colon

> Web Animations API: grouping and sequencing animations

to separate the category (“Web Animations API”) from the the topic (“grouping and sequencing animations”) of the blog post.

Comment: There's little to choose between them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: Use either; the colon is probably considered more formal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah ok, thanks. I thought the English language has strict rules for this type of stuff :)

Comment: The terms 'English language' and 'strict rules' are somewhat contradictory.